# integrating XYZ sensor with Turtlebot...?

Tags: localization, navigation, ekf, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
I would appreciate much if you can give me a north on how to integrate a sensor which gives me x,y and z coordinates data with the Turtlebot robot using ROS.
I guess the robot_pose_ekf package is a good place to start.

We have the sensor. it is a non commercial sensor. it just gives me the spherical coordinates with respect to a fixed beacon. I can convert these to cartesian coordinates. I would like to integrate this data as part of ROS odometry and use it for the Turtlebot.

I would appreciate much your response.

Regards,
Luis.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/260910/integrating-xyz-sensor-with-turtlebot...-?/) by [lmsb](https://answers.ros.org/users/30241/lmsb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-05-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Use hokoyo lidar to configure it in ROS, Its ROS support is avaialble.

---

Originally posted by [Waleed_Shahzaib](https://answers.ros.org/users/28961/waleed_shahzaib/) with karma: 49 on 2017-05-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lmsb](https://answers.ros.org/users/30241/lmsb/) on 2017-05-03**:
Thanks. I should be more specific. We have the sensor. it is a non commercial sensor. it just gives me the spherical coordinates with respect to a fixed beacon. I can convert these to cartesian coordinates. I would like to integrate this data as part of ROS odometry and use it for the Turtlebot.